# JSP code to view request and response and session contents

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to debug an issue where either the HTTP Session is being dropped or the cookie is not being sent back by the browser. Due to the security contstraints that we have to deal with, I am left with needing a JSP That I can drop on the server that will display the contents of the Request, the Response, and the contents of the HTTP Session.

Does anyone have any code that will do this? It should be a self-contained JSP that I can drop into an existing WAR file (so assume I only have access to the default Sun java libraries).

Comment: You need to define "default Sun java libraries" more clearly. As per your comment on my deleted answer, apparently the standard JSP/Servlet/JSTL/EL libraries doesn't fall in this category.

Comment: You should be able to create some simple JSP tags to dump this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the below in a jsp file and and you will get all the info you asked for

```
<%

out.println("<h1>application scope</h1>");
java.util.Enumeration e=application.getAttributeNames();
out.println("<table border='3' width='1000px'>");
while(e.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String name=(String)e.nextElement();

        Object value=application.getAttribute(name);
        if(value==null)
        {
        value="NONE";
        }
        System.out.println(name+":"+value);
        if(!name.contains("ibm") && !name.contains("myfaces")       )
        {
            if(value!=null && value.getClass().toString().contains("versata"))
            {
                out.println("<tr style='font-weight:bold;color:red;'>");        
            }
            else
            {
                out.println("<tr>");    
            }
                out.println("<td>");        
                out.println("Name: "+name);
                out.println("</td>");       
                out.println("<td>");        
                out.println("Value: "+value);
                out.println("</td>");       
                if(value!=null)
                {
                out.println("<td>");        
                out.println("Class: "+value.getClass());
                out.println("</td>");       
                }
                out.println("</tr>");       
        }
    }
out.println("</table>");
out.println("<h1>session scope</h1>");

e=session.getAttributeNames();
out.println("<table border='3' width='1000px'>");
while(e.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String name=(String)e.nextElement();

        Object value=application.getAttribute(name);
        if(value==null)
        {
        value="NONE";
        }
        System.out.println(name+":"+value);
        if(!name.contains("ibm") && !name.contains("myfaces")       )
        {
            if(value!=null && value.getClass().toString().contains("versata"))
            {
                out.println("<tr style='font-weight:bold;color:red;'>");        
            }
            else
            {
                out.println("<tr>");    
            }
                out.println("<td>");        
                out.println("Name: "+name);
                out.println("</td>");       
                out.println("<td>");        
                out.println("Value: "+value);
                out.println("</td>");       
                if(value!=null)
                {
                out.println("<td>");        
                out.println("Class: "+value.getClass());
                out.println("</td>");       
                }
                out.println("</tr>");       
        }
    }
out.println("</table>");

out.println("<h1>request scope</h1>");

e=request.getAttributeNames();
out.println("<table border='3' width='1000px'>");
while(e.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String name=(String)e.nextElement();

        Object value=application.getAttribute(name);
        if(value==null)
        {
        value="NONE";
        }
        System.out.println(name+":"+value);
        if(!name.contains("ibm") && !name.contains("myfaces")       )
        {
            if(value!=null && value.getClass().toString().contains("versata"))
            {
                out.println("<tr style='font-weight:bold;color:red;'>");        
            }
            else
            {
                out.println("<tr>");    
            }
                out.println("<td>");        
                out.println("Name: "+name);
                out.println("</td>");       
                out.println("<td>");        
                out.println("Value: "+value);
                out.println("</td>");       
                if(value!=null)
                {
                out.println("<td>");        
                out.println("Class: "+value.getClass());
                out.println("</td>");       
                }
                out.println("</tr>");       
        }
    }
out.println("</table>");

%>
```

Comment: this is missing the response headers. i need those.

Comment: Bah, this is meant as a dropin solution to be used to troubleshoot a problem. raw Java code in the JSP in this case is what I need